# Pyvisa: creating second instance of ResourceManager

Tags: usb, visa, pyvisa

In my code I want to potentially create multiple instances of `pyvisa.ResourceManager`. However, I the second instance never finds any (USB) devices. Directly addressing the device will also create an error. Essentially my question is as following: why does the following code first print a list with one connected element, and then an empty list:

```
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    print(rm.list_resources())
    rm.close()
    rm2 = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    print(rm2.list_resources())
```

Of course, I could fix this, by only creating one instance, and passing it around, however I would still like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: That's not what I expect. Are you using Keysight or NI for your underlying visa library? Do you know how to use your visa tools (IO Monitor for Keysight, I don't know the name for NI) to track visa calls?

Comment: Also have you checked the return codes from all your visa calls?

Comment: Thanks @ThePhoton for the reply. To be completely honest, I'm not sure what visa I have installed, since it seems to have come with the installation of some other software (prob. Matlab or Thorlabs?). Is there a way to figure out? Therefore I am not aware of any visa tools. I might install another visa, but I am slightly worried I might break something else. What do you mean with return codes?